# The favorite movie puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

Here is a list of my favorite movies in order.

> The Godfather II
>
> Ben-Hur
>
> Airplane!
>
> Goodfellas
>
> Dr. Strangelove
>
> Seven Samurai
>
> The Texas Chainsaw Massacre
>
> ?
>
> Once Upon A Time In The West
>
> French Connection

Which movie below replaces the question mark? Why?

1. The Executioner's Song
2. Gandhi
3. The Good,The Bad And The Ugly
4. North By Northwest

Note: Capitalization of words not important.

Hint 1

> Titles are "in order". That and the Knowledge tag.

Hint 2

> Follow the common letter -- also in the title

Comment: any hints? this is hard :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Movie number eight on the list is

> The Executioner's Song

As the movies follow the pattern

> The Godfat**he**r II - helium
>  **Be**n-Hur - beryllium
>  Airpla**ne**! - neon
>  Good**fe**llas - iron
>  Dr. Stran**ge**love - germanium
>  **Se**ven Samurai - selenium
>  The **Te**xas Chainsaw Massacre - tellurium
>  The E**xe**cutioner's Song - xenon
>  On**ce** Upon A Time In The West - cerium
>  F**re**nch Connection - rhenium
>  [ordered by atomic number](https://www.lenntech.com/periodic/number/atomic-number.htm) contains *e.

Comment: "*e where e makes its first appearance" except for in the "the"s

Comment: Good spot Samathingamajig - have removed "first appearance" now from the answer.